# error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'void'. Two classes with same workflow but one throws error

Tags: c++, networking, memory-address, void-pointers, ns-3

I have two functions with a similar workflow. One is an altered example from NS3 and the other a spin on the alteration for a producer node.

**My producer**

```
void
ProactiveProducer::SendData(Name dataName)
{
  // dataName.append(m_postfix);
  // dataName.appendVersion();
  if (!m_active)
    return;

  NS_LOG_FUNCTION_NOARGS();

  auto data = make_shared<Data>();
  data->setName(dataName);
  data->setFreshnessPeriod(::ndn::time::milliseconds(m_freshness.GetMilliSeconds()));

  data->setContent(make_shared< ::ndn::Buffer>(m_virtualPayloadSize));

  Signature signature;
  SignatureInfo signatureInfo(static_cast< ::ndn::tlv::SignatureTypeValue>(255));

  if (m_keyLocator.size() > 0) {
    signatureInfo.setKeyLocator(m_keyLocator);
  }

  signature.setInfo(signatureInfo);
  signature.setValue(::ndn::makeNonNegativeIntegerBlock(::ndn::tlv::SignatureValue, m_signature));

  data->setSignature(signature);

  NS_LOG_INFO("node(" << GetNode()->GetId() << ") responding with Data: " << data->getName());

  // to create real wire encoding
  data->wireEncode();

  m_transmittedDatas(data, this, m_face);
  m_appLink->onReceiveData(*data); 

  ScheduleNextPacket();
}

void
ProactiveProducer::ScheduleNextPacket()
{
  NS_LOG_DEBUG ("m_sendEvent: " << m_sendEvent.IsRunning());
  if (m_firstTime) {
    m_sendEvent = Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(0.0), &ProactiveProducer::SendData(m_prefix), this);
    m_firstTime = false;
  } else if (!m_sendEvent.IsRunning()) {
    m_sendEvent = Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(1.0 / m_frequency), &ProactiveProducer::SendData(m_prefix), this);
  }
}
```

**NS3 consumer**

```
void
ModConsumer::SendPacket()
{
  // if the application isn't running don't do anything
  if (!m_active)
    return;

  NS_LOG_FUNCTION_NOARGS();

  // Will be an invalid packet
  uint32_t seq = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max(); // invalid

  /*
    if the integer is positice the loop runs infinitely --> poor code
    - when the size of the list goes to 0 it will exit and therefore seq will be max int
    - the consumer seems to work based off of packets to be retransmitted.
    - removes the first entry in list of packets to be retransmitted
    - removes packet from list of retransmissions
    - then transmits that?
  */
  while (m_retxSeqs.size()) {
    seq = *m_retxSeqs.begin();
    m_retxSeqs.erase(m_retxSeqs.begin());
    break;
  }

  // will check fail conditions or increment sequence
  if (seq == std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()) {
    // NS_LOG_DEBUG ("Reached max Sequence: " << seq << " max_seq: " << m_seq);
    if (m_seqMax != std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()) {
      if (m_seq >= m_seqMax) {
        NS_LOG_DEBUG ("maximum sequence number has been requested, m_seq: " << m_seq << " m_seqMax: " << m_seqMax);
        return; // we are totally done
      }
    }

    seq = m_seq++;
  }

  shared_ptr<Name> nameWithSequence = make_shared<Name>(m_interestName);
  nameWithSequence->appendSequenceNumber(seq);

  shared_ptr<Interest> interest = make_shared<Interest>();
  interest->setNonce(m_rand->GetValue(0, std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()));
  interest->setName(*nameWithSequence);
  interest->setCanBePrefix(false);
  time::milliseconds interestLifeTime(m_interestLifeTime.GetMilliSeconds());
  interest->setInterestLifetime(interestLifeTime);
  interest->setMustBeFresh(true);

  // NS_LOG_DEBUG ("Requesting Interest: \n" << *interest);
  // NS_LOG_INFO("> Interest for " << seq);

  WillSendOutInterest(seq);

  m_transmittedInterests(interest, this, m_face);
  m_appLink->onReceiveInterest(*interest);

  ScheduleNextPacket();
}

// Yes this is a different class, pasting for convenience
void
ModConsumerCbr::ScheduleNextPacket()
{
  NS_LOG_DEBUG ("m_sendEvent: " << m_sendEvent.IsRunning());
  if (m_firstTime) {
    m_sendEvent = Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(0.0), &ModConsumer::SendPacket, this);
    m_firstTime = false;
  } else if (!m_sendEvent.IsRunning()) {
    m_sendEvent = Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(1.0 / m_frequency), &ModConsumer::SendPacket, this);
  }
}
```

When I run the code, the compiler throws the following error for the producer class

```
error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'void'
    m_sendEvent = Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(0.0), &ProactiveProducer::SendData(m_prefix), this);
```

I think I understand why the error would be thrown. I'm passing a function of type void. It shouldn't be addressable. So I can't understand how the consumer compiles and functions correctly. Any suggestions as to what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to C++.

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Do you really want the address of the return value (which is usually a bad idea) or do you want to pass a function pointer?

Comment: If you look at the working consumer code, you will notice that it doesn't call the functions.

Comment: Why are you passing `ProactiveProducer::m_prefix` to `ProactiveProducer::SendData` ? It's already a class member, it can access `m_prefix`. You could add an overload `void SendData() { return SendData(prefix); }` if you want to keep the original signature for other uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
m_sendEvent = Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(0.0), &ProactiveProducer::SendData(m_prefix), this);
```

to this

```
m_sendEvent = Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(0.0), &ProactiveProducer::SendData, this, m_prefix);
```

Reference: https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_simulator.html#aec5dd434c42edd6c38ef249d2960c321

Comment: what I meant to say is that the second argument is actually an address of a member function without any argument. So argument to method ProactiveProducer::SendData should be passed as an argument to method Simulator::Schedule.
https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_simulator.html#aec5dd434c42edd6c38ef249d2960c321

Comment: I am no expert. But It look like the case in doxygen.

Comment: You are right, but maybe add a link to the reference to show that this overload actually exists. It helps to avoid some confusion ;)

Comment: I see now, thank you very much. I didn't realize I was passing a member function as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

The error message

> error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'void'

is enough clear

In this statement

```
m_sendEvent = Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(0.0), &ProactiveProducer::SendData(m_prefix), this);
```

the second argument is a function call expression that has the type void - the return type of the function `SendData`. So it is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve taking ab address of an incomplete object of the type void that moreover is an rvalue.

Opposite to your code in this statement

```
m_sendEvent = Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(0.0), &ModConsumer::SendPacket, this);
```

there is taken an address of a member function. So these calls are semantically different.